# How to select text with arrow keys in fish shell

Tags: fish

I am a windows user. I am trying Ubuntu via WSL-2. I am struggling to select text with arrow keys in fish shell. I tried so many places to get answer for this question, but no one gave me proper solution. In documentation they wrote about binding for `begin-selection`. But what is the default way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`begin-selection` is a key binding, but it's not enabled in the standard key bindings by default.

You'll need to set some key bindings to begin and end selecting text. For example:

```
bind \e, begin-selection
bind \e. end-selection
```

will set Alt-< and Alt-> to be begin and end select mode, respectively. These can be used with the default Ctrl-X clipboard copy function.

Answer (score 1):

Fish does not support your intended style of selecting text. The `begin-selection` and `end-selection` commands are intended for VI-style selection in VI mode.

See [this feature request](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/8677), [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1295038/in-fish-shell-how-to-select-with-the-cursor-while-shift-is-held) on superuser and [daleeidd/natural-selection](https://github.com/daleeidd/natural-selection) for an attempt to implement shift-select.